Problem: Incorrect Eye Bone Placement After Rigify Generation
I'm using Rigify's cat rig to rig my model, but when I hit the "Generate" button, the eye bones don't align properly with the meta-rig.
I've tried the following solutions, but they didn't work:
Recalculating the bones
Applying all transforms to the armature
However, when I generate the rig, the eye bones are still misplaced. If you download the file and try generating the rig, you'll see the problem with the eye bone placement. How can I fix this?
Here are the files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojVnk-tq_TJmXafo0mrDQBG4NHbMzLXR/view?usp=sharing


How can we download your file :)?

sorry i forgot to post the files:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xHf7v8ehJZQ8rGKDWcRUMp0tdC9IbT1x?usp=sharing
here
